# How to get Trinidad tr:inputText to echo its changed value instantly?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, trinidad

I have the following Trinidad tr:inputText field in my xhtml file that is bound to "value1" in my managed bean class; the inputText field is of type:

org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.core.input.CoreInputText

```
<tr:inputText value="#{myBean.value1}" autoSubmit="true" immediate="true" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.textChangeListener}" styleClass="stylePageTextSmallColored">
</tr:inputText>

<tr:commandButton id="btnCommit" inlineStyle="width:20" immediate="true" text="Commit" action="#{myBean.doCommit()}" styleClass="styleButton">
</tr:commandButton>

public void textChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    log.debug(">> textChangeListener: value=["+(String)e.getNewValue()+"]");
}

public String doCommit() throws Throwable {
    log.debug("In doCommit: value1="+value1);
    value1 = "("+value1+")";
    // I update my database with the modified value1 string here; the database has the correct
    // updated value1 string (with the parentheses).

    // How do I get the modified value1 (above) to echo back to the screen instantly
    // inside the doCommit() method with its changes?
}
```

When I type into this field and change its value then press the "commit" button, I can see its value properly obtained from the screen in the doCommit() method and the textChangeListener() method indicates that it has been called. I would like to make some changes to the "value1" variable and echo its value back instantly to the screen without doing another screen submit; can this be done as part of the doCommit() method or through some other mechanism/tag in the xhtml file?

Please note that this is using Trinidad and the input text class is listed above.

Update...

Thank you for the reference Jasper; I want the SAME inputText field to update itself after the setter method is called and the input text is changed (by the setter method). Thanks to the reference page that you pointed to; I tried the following and it works by using the partialTriggers attribute:

```
<tr:inputText id="myValue" value="#{myBean.value1}" autoSubmit="true" immediate="true" partialTriggers="myValue" valueChangeListener="#{myBean.textChangeListener}" styleClass="stylePageTextSmallColored"> </tr:inputText>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using Trinidad's [Partial Page Rendering](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html).

In short: you need to add an `id` attribute to your input, and have and `tr:outputText` component with a [`partialTriggers`](https://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/ppr.html#partialSubmit_and_partialTriggers) attribute where you refer to the input component.

Minimal implementation in your case would be:

```
<tr:inputText id="value1Input" 
              value="#{myBean.value1}"
              autoSubmit="true"
              immediate="true"/>
<tr:outputText value="value1: #{myBean.value1}"
               partialTriggers="value1Input"/>
```